# Unity - Input System giving me an error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action(...)"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this confused me...
so i decided to try out the new input system, and see what it was about. i watched a tutorial on how to get it working and this was the code that was "supposed" to work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
public class InputTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerInputSystem input;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        input.PlayerControlls.Shoot.performed += test();
    }

    void test()
    {
        Debug.Log("this is cool");
    }
}
```

this really confused me like i said... here is the error message i got:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>`

[image: source 1]

[image: source 2]

[image: source 3]

Comment: I suspect you want to lose the `()` at the end of `test()` - you don't want to *call* `test()` in the `OnEnable` method, you just want to create a delegate with it so that it can be used to subscribe to the `performed` event.

Comment: How are these screenshots relevant to a compilation error due to a syntax issue in your code? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This executes the method `test`:

```
test()
```

So you are trying to assign the *return value* as an event handler.

You simply need to assign a reference to the method itself:

```
input.PlayerControlls.Shoot.performed += test;
```

You also need to change the signature of `test`:

```
void test(CallbackContext context)
```

Which will allow `test` to be implicitly converted to the delegate `Action<CallbackContext>`.