# Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(18,9): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action...'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I fixed the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326240/im-making-a-unity-game-and-adding-controller-support-so-im-making-a-variable-t?noredirect=1#comment127775433_72326240) I get this error: `Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(18,9): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>'` How do I fix it?

This is my code that gets errors:

```
        controls.Gameplay.Move_Left.performed += Left();

        controls.Gameplay.Move_Right.performed += Right();
```

and

```
    void Left()
    {
        rb.AddForce(leftrightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    void Right()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-leftrightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

(There is a simalar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333339/unity-input-system-giving-me-an-error-message-cannot-implicitly-convert-type) but it didn't work)

Please help, I am really stuck and need to get this done soon!
Go to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326240/im-making-a-unity-game-and-adding-controller-support-so-im-making-a-variable-t?noredirect=1#comment127775433_72326240) to get my full code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two problems here.

1. You should be passing the method itself to the event delegate, not the result of calling the method (which is `null`, so there isn't one).
2. You have the wrong method signature.

The error message tells you as much:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>'

It essentially says that it requires a method that takes a `CallbackContext`, but you're trying to pass `void`. This implies 1 and 2 as mentioned above.

So to fix one, we change your code like this:

```cs
controls.Gameplay.Move_Left.performed += Left;
controls.Gameplay.Move_Right.performed += Right;
```

And to fix 2, we need to match the `System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>` signature, which looks like this:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Meaning we need a method that doesn't return anything (`void`) and accepts a `T` (in this case `CalllbackContext`). Fixing your methods to look like this, we get the following:

```cs
void Left(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    rb.AddForce(leftrightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

void Right(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    rb.AddForce(-leftrightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

And now your code is fixed.

Note that I don't use Unity, but understood this information from the error message, so it really does pay to read them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple solution, just can just discard the context and call `Left()` and `Right()`:

```cs
controls.Gameplay.Move_Left.performed += _ => Left();

controls.Gameplay.Move_Right.performed += _ => Right();
```

Comment: Note that you're essentially creating an anonymous method here which discards the context parameter and calls `Left()` or `Right()`. You can see that [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATogC4C2ADogLyIB2AUwDuiAMoB7NgNQAbegGd5FANzUaOdhwB0AUVoC+LRAGpeAfR4A+RABFxASRYq1iAL4uXCZETuOKLrBgadxgQ2C8UCSlZBXlYQJovAX1DEgBPPQMWABU0jgFETMNVUNhwpAATARkBAHN6FgLCdKKcvIFSVHFDAQAPIwBjchLy5DA0bsb++NhXIA=). It's not really important to the result, but I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar  The is a common way cuz ctx often have no special use in the case of `unity new input system`,, if want context it can use ctx => `ctx.ReadValue ()` ... which is not needed in this question..

Comment: I see. I was just slightly alarmed by the "Just use the Context Default delegate" which doesn't really make much sense from a terminology standpoint, so I thought it best to clarify what actually happens. I can totally see the context not being useful though :)